# Unable to run Tor even in terminal, Vidalia exit code 127

Tags: 12.10, software-installation, console, tor

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 (quantal) and I recently installed Tor (32 bits) following the instructions on the [Tor project's page](https://www.torproject.org/docs/debian-vidalia.html.en).
Then I started the script after having it extracted from the console and got this:

```
master@ubuntu:~/tor-browser_en-US$ ./start-tor-browser 

Launching Tor Browser Bundle for Linux in /home/master/tor-browser_en-US
./start-tor-browser: 225: ./start-tor-browser: ./App/vidalia: not found
Vidalia exited abnormally.  Exit code: 127
```

Then I ran Vidalia from the console and:

```
master@ubuntu:~/tor-browser_en-US$ vidalia

(<unknown>:11354): IBUS-WARNING **: Unable to load /var/lib/dbus/machine-id: Failed     to open file '/var/lib/dbus/machine-id': Permission denied
master@ubuntu:~/tor-browser_en-US$ vidalia

(<unknown>:11358): IBUS-WARNING **: Unable to load /var/lib/dbus/machine-id: Failed     to open file '/var/lib/dbus/machine-id': Permission denied
```

And after Vidalia's GUI opens I get the error prompt about starting Tor:

> "Vidalia was unable to start Tor. Check your settings to ensure the correct name and location of your Tor executable is specified."

How can I start Tor?

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo vidalia`?

Comment: @Lucio It does state clearly at [at the official torproject site](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) that tor should not be run with elevated privileges. Running `sudo vidalia` is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need root permissions to open dbus/machine-id by default (as recommended in one of the comments).
On 14.04 it's rw-r--r-- root:root.

If the file doesn't exist, it can be created with:

```
dbus-uuidgen --ensure
```

[reference with explanation of what it is, and what it does in broad strokes](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-uuidgen.1.html)

That dbus command would need root to create the file with those permissions, or need to be setuid, but I didn't check whether it is or not.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on my 64 Bit-Notebook. There are several OS on it: Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 13.04, Xubuntu 13.04 and Lubuntu 13.04.

The Tor Browser Bundle for 64-Bit GNU/Linux
Version 2.3.25-8 - Linux, Unix, BSD (64-Bit) works on Ubuntu 13.04 and on Lubuntu 13.04 but not on Ubuntu 12.04 and Xubuntu 13.04 !!

The Tor Browser Bundle for GNU/Linux
Version 2.3.25-8 - Linux, Unix, BSD (32-Bit) works on Ubuntu 12.04 and on Xubuntu 13.04

I used the German (de) Version, I don't know if there are any differences.

Herbert

Comment: Please state clearly where your post is actually an answer and not just a comment - it is a little hard to tell.